# How do I create villages?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to [create a village](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/xrgvy/jeb_killing_villagers_face_the_consequences/c5pd9mx?context=3). Apparently this is possible as of Minecraft 1.4.2, so how do I do it?

Comment: Do you want a iron farm, an empty village, or a populated village?

Comment: Very interested in this. @JeffreyLin Maybe an answer could incorporate how to create each kind?

Comment: Yep, I'm currently in the progress of writing one.

Comment: @Jeff Assume *at least* populated. How to build an empty village is a trivial task that no-one is going to think couldn't be done before 1.4.2.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What about the iron farm?

Comment: @JeffreyLin Go for it

Comment: @Jeff You need an occupied village before iron golems spawn, right? I think it's pretty safe to assume they're asking about the new functionality in 1.4.2 that lets you create new NPC villages that function like generated villages. The question would be nonsense otherwise.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not as much nonsense as this question: "How do I banana?"

Comment: @Alex True enough! I personally think nonsense is a "big tent" with room for a wide variety of senselessness. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to create a new village:

1. [Transplant villagers from an existing village](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_NPC_Villages): It's possible to transport villagers from an existing village, such as by placing them in a minecart, but two criteria must be met for them to stay where you unload them:

- They must be at least 32 blocks from the "center" of the existing village, or else they will simply return to the village.
- There must be homes at the new village, or else they will simply wander.

  The wiki discusses [what constitutes a "house"](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village#Criteria_for_an_acceptable_house) and also suggests a [number of designs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_NPC_Villages#House_designs) you can use.

2. [Cure some zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/83129/15): As the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/83019/15) indicates, zombies that spawn either in the wild or from spawners have a chance (10%) of being a [zombie villager](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager), which can then be cured using a [splash potion of weakness](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splash_potion) and a [golden apple](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Golden_apple). If you build a village according to the links I gave above, you can then populate it with nearby randomly-spawned zombie villagers that you have cured of their zombie status.

Comment: minecraftwiki.net seems to be infected with virus-spreading things, any chance that you can update your links?

Comment: @SverreRabbelier: That's the official Minecraft wiki page, and I don't know of another with that same content. I'll give them some time to get their site straight, but if they keep having problems I'll link [here](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki) instead and try to reproduce some of the original content if I can.

Comment: Looks like they're back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a new village and you've found one, use minecarts. Push a villager in and make sure the tracks lead to where you want your new village. If you haven't found one, cure zombie villagers. When you build the village, doors are all that matter. The number of doors = the number of vilagers. If you have two villagers and enough doors for more, they will breed (just like animals) and a baby villager will be born.