# Will this naturally-spawned (but empty) Village eventually populate?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am playing Minecraft on the Xbox, and am enjoying the recent update.

I started a new world, and was pleased to discover a nearby village. I did not see any villagers, nor have any appeared since I have been playing.

Will villagers spawn later?
Do I need to add more buildings to reach a "minimum size" for the village?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NPC Villages were added to Minecraft in beta 1.8, which the current XBox edition version is based on. However, Villagers themselves were not added until beta 1.9, which the next major XBox version will be based on.

So, within the current version/patch, the village will not populate, since Villagers are not in the game yet.

Once the XBox edition is updated to later versions of Minecraft, there is hope that you can populate your villages. I don't know if they will make Villagers automatically spawn in existing villages, but even if they don't, you have hope according to the answers to this question: [How do I create villages?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91582/how-do-i-create-villages) (That is, by curing Zombie Villagers)

Comment: I didn't think they would implement villages without villagers. At least they are cool to look at.