# Will a natural Village repopulate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91719/will-this-naturally-spawned-but-empty-village-eventually-populate) about an empty Minecraft village, but it was about an earlier update.

I was wondering, if a naturally spawned village, for whatever reason, is emptied out (zombie apocalypse, crazed player rampage, an unfortunate incident involving testing with commands that turn all mobs into pigs...) will the village be naturally re-populated? Or will the player have to intervene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has already pointed, as with real life, you need at least two people to repopulate the earth (or in this case, a village) from scratch.

Keep in mind, there are also a few more restrictions.

First, the village needs to have enough houses for the villagers to live in. What the game does behind the scenes is count "doors" rather than buildings, and a good rule of thumb for every three doors, one villager can exist. So if you want a village to host 10 villagers, you will need to have roughly 30 "valid" doors close enough to be inside the village boundries. This means if any doors were destroyed by zombie sieges, you are going to need to go around and put some doors back up until there are enough homes to go around.

Second, newer changes to villager breeding mechanics have "limited" to villages only deciding to breed if (1) a player trades with them, or (2) a player "feeds" them by throwing food at them and having them pick it up. Villagers then have a *random* chance whether to decide to breed or not for a short while.

In order for villages to be "self sufficient" (not requiring the player to come and maintain the village in order for it to grow) the developers implemented a system in which #2 will be automatically done by farmer villagers (the ones with the brown coats); their AI will harvest crops, and then give the resulting food to other villagers, helping them to breed. Note that since Farmers are the *only* villager that does this, if your village does not contain any, you will manually need to help villagers with their breeding!

More technical details can be found on the wiki: [*MineCraft Wiki: Villager Breeding*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding)

Comment: Minecraft not MineCraft, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Once all villagers are dead a village will no longer repopulate. You can revive villagers using mods but thats it.

If you revive a villager you will need to revive 2 in order to repopulate.

Comment: That raised a thought: You can cure a zombie villager, so if you cure one in a village, will they "move back in"?

Comment: @Ben See edit above.

Comment: If I destroy all doors does not it recreates the village and then it has to populate on its own?

Answer (score -1):

As long as at least two villagers remain, the village will repopulate, very sloooooooowly.